# Are these definitions for the $\mathcal{O}$-Notation equivalent?

Tags: functions, asymptotics

The following definitions are used to evaluate the running time behaviour of algorithms. $\mathcal{O}_1$ intuitively ignores a finite number of funtion values at the start of the function, and $\mathcal{O}_2 $ similarly adds a constant factor d to $g(n)$, which essentially does the same. Does it? Are there functions, which are in one set but not the other?

$$f \in \mathcal{O}_1(g) \Leftrightarrow \{f \in F:\exists c>0 \exists n_0>0 \forall n\ge n_0: f(n) \le c \cdot g(n)\}$$

$$f \in \mathcal{O}_2(g) \Leftrightarrow \{f \in F:\exists c,d>0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f(n) \le c \cdot g(n)+d\}$$

Here, F is defined as a set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}_0^{+}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want $$\frac{1}{n} \in \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$  False for $\mathcal{O}_1$, true for $\mathcal{O}_2$.  Perhaps you want to limit yourself only to cases with $g(n) \to +\infty$ ?   Also, you didn't say whether $g(n)=0$ for some $n$ is allowed.